# PGFPlots % in ticks labels

Tags: pgfplots

Hi i want to put this simbol "%" in the tick labels only in the x axis how can i do?[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,\%`. `xticklabel` defines the code used for printing the tick labels, and `\tick` contains the current tick value.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,\%
]
\addplot{rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: since the tick labels are typeset using the maths fonts, if one uses a slightly different font due to using `unicode-math`, it might be more appropriate to use `xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\(\,\%\)`.