# How to change xticklabel or yticklabel style to Percentage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When using `tikzpicture` in the `pgfplots` package, how can I change use PERCENTAGE for xticklabel or yticklabel.

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Rate]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,0.003)
        (3,0.004)
        (4,0.005)
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I change the yticklabel to percentage style: i.e. 0.3%, 0.4%, 0.5%, etc.

I checked the documentation `pdfplots.pdf` and `pdfplotstable.pdf`. There are many Number Printing Settings available but I couldn't find anything that can covert the numbers to percentage style.

Thanks to all for your help! This is what I have right now. It still has problems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Rate,
        scaled ticks=false,
        yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,\%,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,0.003)
        (3,0.004)
        (4,0.005)
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58566/pgfplots-in-ticks-labels Is that right?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: One more problem: The other question works well for number like 3%, 4%, 5%, etc, not for 0.3%, 0.4%, 0.5%. It just shows 3% 4% 5% and on top of the graph it has 10^(-3)

Comment: the relevant keys are given in for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35909/pgfplot-accuracy-of-tick-labels

Comment: Yes. I tried that before, it works well for numbers with many decimals, but it doesn't work when combined with  xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,\%    I updated my post with what I have right now.

Comment: @Titanic: By "it doesn't work", do you mean that the y axis label is overlapping the y tick labels? In that case, just set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` (or whatever version of PGFPlots you're using, as long as it's newer than `1.4`.

Answer (score 13):

A collection of comments

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Rate,
        scaled ticks=false,
        yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,0.003)
        (3,0.004)
        (4,0.005)
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]